# Laravel5.4 - login with facebook in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

Have a nice day,
I am facing issue when I try to do login with facebook. I did all steps in this tutorial http://laravelcode.com/post/laravel54-login-with-facebook-in-laravel

and when I try to login using through facebook it gives me this message
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Many thanks and best regards,

Comment: are u in development or production?

Comment: I am in development